# Column Alignment in QTreeView | PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I horizontally align a column (all items of this column) of a QTreeView? I am using the QStandardItemModel(). I have searched, but I have not found any relevant documentation.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to horizontally align the *contents* of each item for that column? What model are you using on the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note: the proposed solution is only valid for basic cases as the one asked by the OP (a simple QStandardItemModel or any subclassed model that provides basic model data display); read more at the bottom of this answer</sup>

You can subclass the model and override the `data()` function in order to return a proper [Qt.AlignmentFlag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum) when the `Qt.TextAlignmentRole` is requested, which, by default, is None unless manually set with `setData()` or `item.setTextAlignment()`: when the returned value is `None`, the alignment is decided by the *view*, and is normally based on the system's layout direction.

In the following example, you can set an arbitrary *default* alignment for any column (or use `None` to restore it) which will be used unless the alignment has been explicitly set as written above.

```
class AlignModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.columnAlignments = {}

    def setColumnAlignment(self, column, alignment):
        if alignment:
            self.columnAlignments[column] = alignment
        elif column in self.columnAlignments:
            self.columnAlignments.pop(column)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return (super().data(index, role) or 
                self.columnAlignments.get(index.column()))
        return super().data(index, role)

# set the center alignment for the *second* column:
model = AlignModel()
model.setColumnAlignment(1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Note that `Qt.AlignCenter` implies both `Qt.AlignVCenter` and `Qt.AlignHCenter` (through an OR operator), so if you want to align to the right or the left, you must also provide the vertical alignment: for example, `Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter`.

### Some important notes:

As [indicated by eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67754240/2001654), the common suggestion is to use a delegate instead of subclassing the model. While my solution is fine for situations where a very simple solution is required (and a model can be actually used, which is not the case for higher the level classes, QTreeWidget, QTableWidget and QListWidget), the general rule is that the model should *never* return "changed" contents: the returned value from `data()` should always reflect the actual contents of the index, and any modifications (including displaying data such as text alignment) should happen using a proxy model or by changing the behavior of the delegate.
This is very important from the modular point of view typical of OOP, especially considering the MVC (or MV, for Qt) pattern: the model (the *real* data) and the view (how the data is shown) should be distinct and independent.

Take for instance this very case: text alignment. Let's suppose that the alignment should be towards the "beginning" of the first column: for right-to-left languages that would mean aligning the text on the right (since the first column is on the right edge); if the model is going to be serialized, the result is that alignment would be dependent on the *source* layout of the serialization, while the alignment should be completely dependent on the layout of the user viewing (unserializing) it.
So, that's what you should ask: is the text alignment important for the model (for example, the data could contain text in various languages with different writing directions), or for the view? If any of that doesn't really matter, then you have to think about what's the best solution, performance-wise: for instance, if you're going to have a very big model (with thousands of entries, and possibly hundreds of items shown at the same time), and you're sure that a certain column is going to always have the same alignment, then you could override `data()` or use a QIdentityProxyModel, which would be certainly faster than using a delegate and overriding the `paint` method.
In any other case, the delegate solution is a more correct and coherent one, as it also allows displaying the same model data in different ways, no matter what the contents are.

Comment: Although your update is interesting, I do not agree: what do we define as data or model? Well, the basic information and that may or may not cover the alignment of the text. So that's based on opinions. For example, let's do an example: should a comma or a period be used to separate the integer part from the decimals? Well, the data (the model) should not have that information but the view taking information from the locale should do it.

Comment: Just as you point out in your last line: the delegate is used to customize the view using the same model (without modifying it), and from my point of view the text alignment fulfills that function.

Comment: The proxy-models are also an attempt to do so, that is, to modify the information it provides but without modifying the base information (the background model).

Comment: @eyllanesc I completely agree (and I should try to rephrase parts of my update). What I was trying to explain is that: 1. there are many situations for which a model is just a simple and direct visualisation of data that isn't really going to be used in any other way (cases for which one might use a QTreeWidget, but needs more advanced features); 2. text alignment *can be* part of the "view" (at least, to some extent, depending on the situation) just as it could be important right from the model contents; 3. 1+2+performance: as soon as there's complete control (and awareness!) of the model, ->

Comment: Note: In performance your solution is equivalent to mine (I wanted to point out using the same storage and data collection logic as yours)

Comment: -> its behavior/implementation, and its final usage, one might choose any of the solutions (`data()` reimplementation, proxy model, or delegate) based on the actual and final requirements.

Comment: @eyllanesc uhm. Do you confirm that using a basic `data()` reimplementation is actually the same as using `initStyleOption` of a (and *with* a) delegate, even with hundreds or thousands of items currently shown on the view, and even considering scrolling performance?

Comment: @musicamante Yes, in the end `initStyleOption()` invokes `data()`. Check the source code: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp.html#289

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I know, but the question still raises: isn't having an alternate delegate *and* implementing the python code cause some difference? Is it really as negligible even for large amount of items?

Comment: Doesn't the same logic apply to having a model written in python? If you want to have the same efficiency as C++ then use C++. PyQt and PySide, being a Qt wrapper, also have these differences.

Comment: Fair point: since the OP was using a QStandardItemModel, it wouldn't change that much between subclassing the model or using a delegate's `initStyleOption`. Actually, it could be even worse, now that I think about it. I'll do some testing and update the answer accordingly. Thank you, as usual :-)

Answer (score 3):

Solutions that do not involve inheriting from the model (which is sometimes a limitation such as QListWidget, QTableWidget or QTreeWidget) are:

- Use a proxy model (QIdentityProxyModel for example).
- Use delegates.

In this case I will use the last solution:

```py
from functools import cached_property


class AlignmentDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    @cached_property
    def alignment(self):
        return dict()

    def set_column_alignment(self, column, alignment):
        self.alignment[column] = alignment

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        alignment = self.alignment.get(index.column(), None)
        if alignment is not None:
            option.displayAlignment = alignment
```

```
delegate = AlignmentDelegate(self.view)
self.view.setItemDelegate(delegate)
delegate.set_column_alignment(1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

The advantage of the previous method is that it can be applied to any model and is easy to modify.